# Flask blueprint/app factory circular import

Tags: flask, circular-dependency, blueprint

I realise that blueprints are meant for modularity, and perform this task well. However, I have several tasks that are required by multiple blueprints as well as the root application (i.e. `app/`). With this mind, when I make changes to the tasks in `app/tasks.py` I would like it to propagate out to the blueprints that use these tasks without me having to manual change the code in each blueprints' task file (`app/blueprint/tasks.py`).

With this in mind I am trying to import `app/tasks.py` into each of the blueprints that has a copy of some task in `app/tasks.py` in `app/blueprint/tasks.py`. Of course, the main issue here is circular imports and I can't seem to get around them, in fact it seems almost impossible. My app factory does not import `app/tasks.py` until it has returned to application. Is it possible to make this import prior to registering the blueprints in the factory itself? If not, is there any way to circumvent the circular import problem? At the moment I see no way around it, there is no where to place `from app import tasks` in the blueprint files without creating a circular import.

EDIT: I realised the issue was that I registered my blueprints in my app factory. So when I would attempt `from app.tasks import <func>` in `app/blueprint/tasks.py` it would raise an import error since `app` had not been declared at the point of blueprint registration. I could get around this by moving the blueprint registration outside the app factory but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see it should work? Could it be that it is confusing things due to naming? As in thinking that the app is refering to app object and not the folder?

I just tested in my own app and i can import same things into app.py and my blueprint files.

Try maybe changing the folder names so they are not named app.